# how to calculate number of tokens in a file nlp

Tags: python

```
from urllib import request
from redditscore.tokenizer import CrazyTokenizer
tokenizer = CrazyTokenizer()
url = "http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi5386/A1_2020/microblog2011.txt"
with open('your_file.txt', 'a',encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as f:
    for line in request.urlopen(url):
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(line.decode('utf-8'))
        print(tokens)
        for item in tokens:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Tokenizer splits the sentences into words.In the above code my output is in the file in the form of tokens  (1
to
carbon
monoxide
non
medical
concord
ave
b
w
ln
1
n
northumberland
w
concor
ln
2
n
northumberland
w)
The output will be in the tokens in the form of list, Then i converted this list into a text file.

How to calculate the number of tokens in that file?

Please help...

Comment: Hi @leo welcome to the community, It would be helpful if you can add more context to your question. Does tokens become an array? what does the `tokenizer` do? When asking questions be as specific as possible and help us understand what is it that your asking.

Comment: with open('your_file.txt', 'r',encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as f:
  list_  = f.readlines()

Comment: len(list_) wll give you number of token